# I have problem with the comment font in android studio

Tags: android-studio, comments

I want to write a comment with my code in android studio but the font style is not clear, 
who can I change it?

pic for the problem
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KEVrJ.jpg

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to change the font in settings

1. On Windows: File -> Settings
2. On Mac: Android Studio -> Preferences

IDE Settings -> Editor -> Colors & Fonts -> Font

Comment: it only changes the code font, not the comment font.